# Drawing a path between two points

Tags: c#, math, windows-phone-7, xna

I'm working on a touch based game, and I'm having issues drawing a path the user has touched through.
I'm trying to mimic something like these apps http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3CECr6mT1Q or http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r34-_0wrVC4

I'm doing this in XNA/C#.

**My issue is**: I have the set of waypoints that define that users touch path. I wasnt sure how I could get a stylized line between all these points, so I thought "hey, I will just have a really small image that is 'the line', and draw it at every spot between the waypoints, and rotate it accordingly. I'm not sure this if this is the best solution or not.

But I was stuck because I did not know how to get all the coordinates between these two points. I have the two points, I can get a vector from the first to second, etc, but I cant seem to get the math correct.

Any suggestions or help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To compute an intermediate point between two points find the direction vector from one point to the other and the distance between the points.  Scale the distance by a factor t between 0 and 1 where t = 0 corresponds to the first point t = 0.5 is half way between them and t = 1 corresponds to the second point.  Then scale the direction vector by this value and add it to the original point.

```
Vector2 IntermediatePoint(Vector2 p0, Vector2 p1, float t)
{
    Vector2 delta = p1 - p0;

    float distance = delta.Length();

    if (distance == 0.0f)
    {
        return p0;
    }
    else
    {
        Vector2 direction = delta / distance;

        return p0 + direction * (distance * t);
    }
}
```

If you compute multiple points between p0 and p1 you should only calculate the distance and direction once.

You could also look into using [XNA RoundLine](http://roundline.codeplex.com/) to connect your points.

Another suggestion is to [set up a textured rotated quad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270138/how-do-i-draw-lines-using-xna).

Comment: Empyrean - THANKS! That worked like a charm! Much appreciated! Do you know if your code is more or less the same way XNA would draw primitives, or would I be taking a perf hit? Also, I'll post my code snippet incase someone ventures on this thread in the future. Additionally, roundLine looks really cool, I'll check it out.

Comment: Computing the length of a vector is an expensive operation.  But not too expensive for what you are doing here.  XNA does not do this as part of it's line drawing primitive.  I don't recommend using the line drawing primitive however.  As you suggest in your question, it is not customizable at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
pointA = waypointsToDraw.ElementAt(i);
pointB = waypointsToDraw.ElementAt(i + 1);
deltaVector = pointB - pointA;
distance = deltaVector.Length();
direction = deltaVector / distance;
for (int z = 1; z < distance; z++)
{
    newPoint = pointA + direction * (distance * (z/distance));
    //this is the newPoint - it will be every point/pixel between pointA and pointB. Put drawing code here

}
```

Code samples above. PointA and pointB is the two end points, newPoint will be every point between them

Comment: I suggest making z be of type float to avoid int to float conversion once per loop when you divide by distance.  Try to avoid mixing types in math operations for optimal performance.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I'll keep it in mind. Just to keep the learning exercise going, if I wanted to apply a bezier curve or catmull-rom spline to the above - would it be easy to tweak the above for this? :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the sample at http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/primitives for details on how to draw simple "Primitives" including a line.

Comment: thanks, but I've actually already taken a look at that before. From looking at that, I wasnt sure how I would be able to customize their line to be something a bit more attractive - the only customization I found was the color option. I also think they're having XNA do alot of the calculations for drawing, thus I cant see their math for how they did it.