# Best way to draw a simple line with Windows Phone 7 XNA

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm REALLY new to programming on Windows Phone 7.

How would I draw a line from point (x1,y1) to point (x2,y2).

I'm using the XNA Game Studio, and can do a lot in there, but need to be able to draw some simple shapes with lines like I would on a basic Canvas.

Is there any way to do something like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270138/how-do-i-draw-lines-using-xna

Answer (score 1):

[In book Programming Windows Phone 7 by Charles Petzold](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/) there is a simple lib to draw lines.