# Create curved lines in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

For practice I'd like to create a game like "Achtung, die Kurve" (http://www.achtungdiekurve.net), basically a hybrid of Tron and Snake, in XNA.
For this I wonder how to draw the curves, considering the line / curve continues to grow and I need some kind of collision detection.
Do you have any suggestions and/or links to code samples on how to tackle this challenge?
Thx

Comment: The collision detection should come under a different question.

Comment: Consider modifying http://roundline.codeplex.com/ to suit your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XNA Curve Creator shows you how to use the Curve class:  http://creators.xna.com/en-US/utilities/curveeditor

More information about the Curve class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.curve.aspx

And here is a demonstration on how to get the Camera for follow a curve, so I'm sure it could be adjusted for your needs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203908(XNAGameStudio.10).aspx

It also depends on whether or not you want to use a particle based approach or a strip based approach when trailing an object. There are several samples for both approaches, [this older one](http://www.paradeofrain.com/2007/10/continuous-2d-ribbons-in-xna/) for a the strip method or [this sample](http://www.catalinzima.com/samples/game-features-replicator/world-of-goo-cursor/) for the particle-based method.

Use [GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196411.aspx). Generate a list of vertices from either the previous positions of your sprites, or use the Curve class linked above if sprite movement is too jagged.

Ref: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/60257/370769.aspx
Ref: [How do I draw lines using XNA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270138/how-do-i-draw-lines-using-xna)